# Ionic3 and SQLite - create table using property as table name inside query

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, create-table

I'm making an app using Ionic 3 and SQLite. I tried to create a table using a property as table name inside the query but it returns this error:

> 'sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: near "(": syntax error'

Here's the code that I used:

```
onCreateTb() {
  this.database.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS (?) (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, skill TEXT, yearsOfExperience INTEGER)', [this.tableName])
    .then(() => console.log('Ok'))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

In various articles about SQLite I saw the (?) marker on `INSERT` queries but never on `CREATE TABLE` queries.

How can I use a property as a table name?

Comment: You can't use a bound parameter as a table or column name. They have to be directly present in the SQL statement string.

Comment: @Shawn I tried doing ('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + this.tableName + ' (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, skill TEXT, yearsOfExperience INTEGER)', []) and it worked. Is this ok or is it a bad practice? Is there a better way of implementing variables as tables and columns names?

Comment: As long as you have control over what the name is and nobody can use it as a vector for a SQL injection attack, it's okay. Not ideal but there aren't really other options. Sticking the table name in double quotes in case it shares a name with a SQL keyword or otherwise is an invalid unquoted identifier can't hurt either. (But better to avoid such names in the first place)

Comment: Also, read this before using AUTOINCREMENT if you haven't already: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: @Shawn I haven't read yet. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Shawn So, if I use 'rowid' as column name, it will have almost the same behavior as if I used 'AUTOINCREMENT', except it will reasign an id number of previously removed rows to new rows. Is that it?

Comment: No... read that documentation again (And [this bit](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)). While you can use it as an explicit column name, rowid is the implicit name for the key; most people use 'id' or something descriptive that makes sense for the table when aliasing it. `AUTOINCREMENT` changes what happens when the rowid overflows a signed 64 bit integer (Which, unless you're manually inserting values near that limit, will never happen), or if you delete the current maximum rowid. It really should have been called something else with a less confusing name.